# How to click on a ReactJS wrapping element?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-events

When I click a wrapping element, I'd expect a function to trigger on that wrapping element. Instead it seems to trigger on the most-inner element.

In the case below, clicking on "yo" logs `undefined`; clicking on the space between "yo" and "lip" logs `1`; and clicking on "lip" logs `undefined`.

I would expect all 3 to log `1`.

```
import React from 'react';

export default class Foo extends React.Component {
  something = e => {
    e.stopPropagation()
    console.log(e.target.dataset.index)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <section data-index={1} onClick={this.something} ref={e => { this.section = e }}>
        <h1 style={{ marginBottom: 30 }}>yo</h1>
        <p>lip</p>
      </section>
    )
  }
}
```

[CodeSandbox Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/4jlorzk774)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will get the behavior you want by using e.currentTarget instead of e.target.

The [docs for e.currentTarget state](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget):

> Identifies the current target for the event, as the event traverses the DOM. It always refers to the element to which the event handler has been attached, as opposed to event.target which identifies the element on which the event occurred.

Here is [a fork of your codesandbox using e.currentTarget](https://codesandbox.io/s/l99l3122vm).

```
import React from 'react';

export default class Foo extends React.Component {
  something = e => {
    e.stopPropagation()
    console.log(e.currentTarget.dataset.index)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <section data-index={1} onClick={this.something} ref={e => { this.section = e }}>
        <h1 style={{ marginBottom: 30 }}>yo</h1>
        <p>lip</p>
      </section>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
import React from 'react';

export default class Foo extends React.Component {
  something = e => {
    e.stopPropagation()
    //console.log(e.target.dataset.index)
    console.log(e.currentTarget.dataset.index)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <section data-index={1} onClick={this.something} ref={e => { this.section = e }}>
        <h1 style={{ marginBottom: 30 }}>yo</h1>
        <p>lip</p>
      </section>
    )
  }
}
```